# How do I get green grass on the beach?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Can anyone tell me how to get green grass on the beach in *Minecraft*?

Comment: are you talking about the color of grassblocks when placed on beaches? Or are you talking about how to get those grass blocks into the beach biome?

Comment: You need to be more specific; are you asking what is the most *efficient* way of getting grass onto a beach?

Answer (score 1):

Grass can't grow on sand. Grass can only spread to nearby dirt blocks.

This means you have to place dirt blocks over your sandy beach, and at least one Grass block. A Grass block can be obtained with a Silk Touch tool, or killing an Enderman holding it.